# SQL injection vulnerability with prepared statement that uses concatenation

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Would parameterized code that uses concatenation in this way have a SQL injection vulnerability?  I assume that it would, but I'm not certain what POST data would exploit it.

```
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
          $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
          $columns .= $key;
          $holders .= ($holders == "") ? "" : ", ";
          $holders .= ":".$value;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO request ($columns) VALUES ($holders)";

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
          $field = ":".$key;
          $stmt->bindValue($field, $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: **It is not safe**, $columns can contain SQL injection. Adding a *whitelist* to guard keys should make this 'safe'.

Comment: Surely you mean yes, it can be vulnerable to sqli - but only if the underlying DBMS supports multiple statements per execute (IIRC you can do this with mysqlnd but you need to jump some extra hoops)

Comment: @symcbean, The SQL injection vulnerability doesn't need multi-query. The attacker can insert data to the database and then if that data is later used in an unsafe way when writing another SQL query, it's called "second-order SQL injection."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array to store all the columns of request table and check if the post key is present in the array.

PHP code:

```
$request_columns = array('column1','column2');// all the columns of request table

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key,$request_columns)){
          $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
          $columns .= $key;
          $holders .= ($holders == "") ? "" : ", ";
          $holders .= ":".$key;
     }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO request ($columns) VALUES ($holders)";

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(in_array($key,$request_columns)){
      $field = ":".$key;
      $stmt->bindValue($field, $value);
   }
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

@KetanYekale is correct that you need to filter $_POST for known column names.

Here's an alternative way of doing it, using some PHP builtin functions.

```
$request_columns = array('column1','column2');// all the columns of request table

# get a subset of $_POST, only those that have keys matching the known request columns
$post_only_columns = array_intersect_key(
  $_POST,
  array_flip($request_column)
);

# make sure columns are delimited like `name` in case they are SQL reserved words
$columns = implode(array_map(function ($col) { return "`$col`"; }, array_keys($post_only_columns), ', ';

# use ? positional holders, not named holders. it's easier in this case
$holders = implode(array_fill(1, count($post_only_columns), '?'), ', ');

$sql = "INSERT INTO request ($columns) VALUES ($holders)";

$stmt => $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

# no need to bindValue() or use a loop, just pass the values to execute()
$stmt->execute( array_values($post_only_columns) );
```

PHP has many [Array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that you can use in different scenarios to make your code faster and more concise. You can use these functions to avoid writing some types of `foreach` looping code.